# Properly overwriting RecyclerView animations

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView in which a display a list of items. I specify the default animator to the RecyclerView like this:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator() );
```

Everything works great, but I want to use my own custom animations for adding/removing/updating the elements in the list.

I defined a custom animator class like this:

```
    public class MyAnimator extends RecyclerView.ItemAnimator {

    @Override
    public  boolean animateDisappearance(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @Nullable ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean animateAppearance(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @Nullable ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean animatePersistence(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public  void runPendingAnimations() {

    }

    @Override
    public  void endAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {

    }

    @Override
    public  void endAnimations() {

    }

    @Override
    public  boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And set it the same way as I did for DefaultItemAnimator. The animations are not playing anymore, so I guess it worked, but the problem is that items get stacked sometimes on top of each other, and when I remove all the items, some are still left, so I guess I'm missing something.

As far as I understood animateDisappearance is a method that gets called, when the item is removed from the list. If I return false, it should simply skip the animation as far as I understood, correct?

Am I even on the right track? when I look for examples of this on github, there are very few results and overall I can't seem to find any basic code example how to do this, and the ones I found are all thousands of lines of codes.

How can I simply overwrite the default add/remove animations with my own without using any external libraries? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I was able to override the default animation the following way:

```
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator() {
            @Override
            public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
                holder.itemView.clearAnimation();
                final RecyclerView.ViewHolder h = holder;
                holder.itemView.animate()
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2.f))
                        .setDuration(1350)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                dispatchRemoveFinished(h);
                            }
                        })
                        .start();
                //
                return false;
            }
        } );
```

The animation works perfectly, but for some reason it seems like 'dispatchRemoveFinished' is triggered instantly, so instead of the remaining elements adjusting AFTER the animation, they do it instantly as soon as the view is removed. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators/tree/master/animators/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/recyclerview/animators ...has some examples for that.

Comment: To use any of these I need to use the BaseItemAnimator class, which is almost 1k lines of code: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators/blob/cbbe9d6fcafb4b8e7c1847e9fc56f110889f9dc3/animators/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/recyclerview/animators/BaseItemAnimator.java Is that the only way to override the default animations? It seems there should be a shorter way, is there?

Comment: this is the `DefaultItemAnimator`: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.java - where you could skip implementing some interface methods and just call `super.methodName()` inside them...unless calling to the `super` class, just returning `false`, will not work out.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I fully understood. Do you mean overriding DefaultItemAnimator methods (like I did in the edited question) and calling super at the end?

Comment: You need to implement `animatePersistence` to animate movement when an item is removed.

Comment: @0x29a what I've meant is, that you would have to call eg. `super.animateRemove(holder);`, just case you would not implement the method. most methods there return `void`  or `boolean` (and not just some static boolean value).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When implementing your `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` you have to follow few rules or RecyclerView state will get messed up:

1. All those empty methods returning false must at least call `dispatchAnimationFinished(viewHolder)` as well to clear animation state.
2. If those methods are to start animation, You should  `dispatchAnimationStarted(viewHolder)`, store animation request and return true to get call to `runPendingAnimations()` where animations should actually begin.
3. You need to keep track of ongoing animations to be able to properly cancel them, You will get requests for items that are already being animated as well.

Here's a sample `ItemAnimator` that animates only removal and movement. Note the inner class that acts as data-holder of animations and listener of animation states:

```
public class RecAnimator extends RecyclerView.ItemAnimator {

private final static String TAG = "RecAnimator";

private final static int ANIMATION_TYPE_DISAPPEAR = 1;
private final static int ANIMATION_TYPE_MOVE = 2;

// must keep track of all pending/ongoing animations.
private final ArrayList<AnimInfo> pending = new ArrayList<>();
private final HashMap<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AnimInfo> disappearances = new HashMap<>();
private final HashMap<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AnimInfo> persistences = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public boolean animateDisappearance(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @Nullable ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
    pending.add(new AnimInfo(viewHolder, ANIMATION_TYPE_DISAPPEAR, 0));
    dispatchAnimationStarted(viewHolder);
    // new pending animation added, return true to indicate we want a call to runPendingAnimations()
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean animateAppearance(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @Nullable ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
    dispatchAnimationFinished(viewHolder);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean animatePersistence(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
    if (preLayoutInfo.top != postLayoutInfo.top) {
        // required movement
        int topDiff = preLayoutInfo.top - postLayoutInfo.top;
        AnimInfo per = persistences.get(viewHolder);
        if(per != null && per.isRunning) {
            // there is already an ongoing animation - update it instead
            per.top = per.holder.itemView.getTranslationY() + topDiff;
            per.start();
            // discard this animatePersistence call
            dispatchAnimationFinished(viewHolder);
            return false;
        }
        pending.add(new AnimInfo(viewHolder, ANIMATION_TYPE_MOVE, topDiff));
        dispatchAnimationStarted(viewHolder);
        // new pending animation added, return true to indicate we want a call to runPendingAnimations()
        return true;
    }
    dispatchAnimationFinished(viewHolder);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
    dispatchAnimationFinished(oldHolder);
    dispatchAnimationFinished(newHolder);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void runPendingAnimations() {
    for (AnimInfo ai: pending) {
        ai.start();
    }
    pending.clear();
}

@Override
public void endAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {
    AnimInfo ai = disappearances.get(item);
    if (ai != null && ai.isRunning) {
        ai.holder.itemView.animate().cancel();
    }
    ai = persistences.get(item);
    if (ai != null && ai.isRunning) {
        ai.holder.itemView.animate().cancel();
    }
}

@Override
public void endAnimations() {
    for (AnimInfo ai: disappearances.values())
        if (ai.isRunning)
            ai.holder.itemView.animate().cancel();

    for (AnimInfo ai: persistences.values())
        if (ai.isRunning)
            ai.holder.itemView.animate().cancel();
}

@Override
public boolean isRunning() {
    return (!pending.isEmpty()
            || !disappearances.isEmpty()
            || !persistences.isEmpty());
}

/** 
 * This is container for each animation. It's also cancel/end listener for them.
 * */
private final class AnimInfo implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    private final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    private final int animationType;
    private float top;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    private AnimInfo(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int animationType, float top) {
        this.holder = holder;
        this.animationType = animationType;
        this.top = top;
    }

    void start(){
        View itemView = holder.itemView;
        itemView.animate().setListener(this);
        switch (animationType) {
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_DISAPPEAR:
                itemView.setPivotY(0f);
                itemView.animate().scaleX(0f).scaleY(0f).setDuration(getRemoveDuration());
                disappearances.put(holder, this);   // must keep track of all animations
                break;
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_MOVE:
                itemView.setTranslationY(top);
                itemView.animate().translationY(0f).setDuration(getMoveDuration());
                persistences.put(holder, this);     // must keep track of all animations
                break;
        }
        isRunning = true;
    }

    private void resetViewHolderState(){
        // reset state as if no animation was ran
        switch (animationType) {
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_DISAPPEAR:
                holder.itemView.setScaleX(1f);
                holder.itemView.setScaleY(1f);
                break;
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_MOVE:
                holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0f);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        switch (animationType) {
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_DISAPPEAR:
                disappearances.remove(holder);
                break;
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_MOVE:
                persistences.remove(holder);
                break;
        }
        resetViewHolderState();
        holder.itemView.animate().setListener(null); // clear listener
        dispatchAnimationFinished(holder);
        if (!isRunning())
            dispatchAnimationsFinished();
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        // jump to end state
        switch (animationType) {
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_DISAPPEAR:
                holder.itemView.setScaleX(0f);
                holder.itemView.setScaleY(0f);
                break;
            case ANIMATION_TYPE_MOVE:
                holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0f);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
}
}
```

You can also override [SimpleItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SimpleItemAnimator) class that parses `animate...` methods into `animateMove`, `animateRemove` etc. for you.

Comment: Shouldn't isRunning function have || instead of &&? So that it's running when one of lists is not empty?

Comment: @nickeyzzz indeed, must've been a typo since I was referencing `DefaultItemAnimator` which uses OR.