# Android RecyclerView how to make a custom insert animation?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make a custom insert animation in `RecyclerView` when adding items. This is what I got so far:

```
private void init(View view, Context context) {
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.messagesList);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator() {
        @Override
        public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
            holder.itemView.setScaleY(0);
            holder.itemView.animate().scaleY(1).setDuration(3000).start();
            return super.animateAdd(holder);
        }
    });
}

private void onNewItem(Item item){
    adapter.onNewItem(item);
    layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, adapter.getItemCount());
}
```

Then in the adapter

```
private void onNewItem(Item item){
    items.addItem(item);
    notifyItemInserted(items.size());
}
```

The item just appears when it's added, there is no scroll nor custom animation.

Comment: try to replace `super.animateAdd(holder)` with `true`

Comment: @Link182 nop, same result

Comment: then use xml, just define the animation in `res/anim` and connect it to your recycler view with `android:layoutAnimation`, or inflate it from code `recucler.layoutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(view.context, layoutAnimationId)`, dont forget to call `notifyItemInserted()` from your adapter

Comment: You can't just crudely override one method and force animation on viewholder. I suggest checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696530/properly-overwriting-recyclerview-animations/51698920#51698920) where I explained how ItemAnimator basically works or use [RecyclerView Animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) library which already implements your effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `smoothScrollToPosition` with `scrollToPosition` solved the problem.

Also I had a bug calling to `notifyItemInserted(items.size());` instead of `notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);`